# Do I need multiple network drivers for my PXE Windows 7 64-bit WinPE?

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, pxe, winpe

We are working on a PXE Server which is Linux-based with a Debian distribution. Our server is running fine and we can PXE boot clients with Linux distributions.

Now we are adding a Windows 7 installation option. We intend to PXE boot a Windows PE environment and continue by accessing a Windows 7 installation ISO on the network.

I need help with creating a WinPE ISO which is capable of accessing the network from inside the WinPE environment. However, we have problems with getting the WinPE environment to access the network.

Do I need to create different WinPEs for different network cards or can I add multiple network drivers to one WinPE ISO?

Comment: Are you asking how to add the required network drivers to the .ISO?  You download the network drivers from the OEM website.

Comment: You might also look into MDT (Microsoft Deployment Toolkit) if you have a Windows Server with WDS installed.

Answer (score 0):

Driver files are .inf files. To get the Network adapter files you will need to download the appropriate Network Driver files for each model of PC you are planning to PXE boot. You can often extract the exe file to get access to the required inf files.
Sometimes multiple models will be covered by one driver file, i.e Intel onboard network drivers.
What are you going to be using to PXE boot? SCCM, WDS? Depending on what your back end will be you can often just inject the inf files using the GUI. Otherwise you'll be playing about with dism to inject the drivers.

Comment: Well since the PXE Server will be Linux based, the only Windows  Tools that we will be using is the AIK kit and th DISM. Thats why I was asking if there was a all for one driver.

Comment: In that case I suggest you read the following technet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn613857.aspx

Comment: @Felix - You told us nothing about the hardware you have.

Comment: @Ramhound - Ah sorry about that. As far as I could see we are yousing the onboard network cards, the Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller. So if that doesn't change we should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter way to soon:         @Ramhound - Ah sorry about that. As far as I could see we are yousing the onboard network cards, the Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, though our Instructor isn't here today so we don't know which PCs should have their network drivers included. But if we keep using the Onboard then we should be fine.    Joe Taylor - Thanks for the link. I have seen simliar instructions on a Windows Website, though these seem better listet. We have been doing it that way up until now, so we just needed the Network Drivers, which led me to posting this question here.

Comment: We need the information in the question not in a comment that is liable to be deleted during a comment cleanup